# How to make two packages with the same path name in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm trying to make two packages in eclipse. One with the name bank.managers and the other with the name bank.managers.db ,But when i try to create the second one, It tells me that a package with that name already exists and if i create them the other way around, It just adds the .db to the same package. How do i solve this?

Comment: Create the *shorter* package, then add a class to it, then create the other package and add a class to it.

Comment: The period character ('.') is the seperator in a package name.  You can not include the period character as part of the package name.

Answer (score 2):

packages are hierarichal in nature. So if you want to create a package `bank.managers.db` and there exists a package `bank.managers` then the `db` package will go under `bank.managers` only.

Comment: How do i cancel the hierarichal thingy for the sake of creating those two packages?

Comment: @user2664618 you will have to chose a different name

Comment: There is a way. I watched a guy in class as he canceled that option and he did manage to create two packages with the same path name

Answer (score 2):

Empty packages are simply hidden. Play with the following options to figure out what's really going on:

- View menu > Empty packages
- View menu > Empty parent packages

Also note that Eclipse can display packages in the Package Explorer in two different styles:

- View menu > Package Presentation > Flat / Hierarchical

The view menu is the little downwards arrow (triangle) in the upper right corner of the Package Explorer view.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that when the package `bank.managers` is empty and you create another package named `db`  under it - i.e. `bank.managers.db` -  then it looks like it just adds `.db` to the existing package. If you look in the file system you'll find it as expected

```
src/bank/manager
```

and

```
src/bank/manager/db
```

When you try to create a new Class then you have to choose the right package. If you right click on the package and do `New > Class` then the package filed in following dialog will contain `bank.manager.db` . If you want to have the new Class under `bank.manager.db`  then just remove `.db`.

That said, with `bank.manager.db` you actually have thee packages

```
bank
bank.manager
bank.manager.db
```

Choose whichever you want when trying to create a new resource!